# Access REST API after Single Sign-on (SSO)

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, single-sign-on

We have a heroku-hosted web app that used Salesforce as Identity Provider (IdP) to do Single Sign-On (SSO) between SFDC & other services. We know that in doing so our web app user are already logged into their SFDC account. Then what is the best way for our web app to obtain SFDC REST API access under user's SFDC account without asking for a password or redirecting?

We have basic understanding on OAuth, SAML and SSO. Also we have studied the following pages:

1. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&language=en_US
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth

Comment: Is the Heroku web app a Service Provider? Does it have access to the SAML Assertion from Salesforce?

Comment: Yes I think our Heroku app will be the SP and it has ability to access SAML Assertion.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a session ID as an attribute in the SAML Assertion. In the Connected App configuration for your SP, set `$Api.Session_ID` as a Custom Attribute value. The recipient will be able to use the session ID with the REST API.

Comment: Once again thank you for your reply. I have tried your solution. It works when I login as internal user with internal login portal.

However it does not work when I login as an external user (community user) using community login portal. It gives the following error message when I use the session id to make REST API call:
`[ {
  "message" : "This session is not valid for use with the REST API",
  "errorCode" : "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
} ]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like communities users are locked down differently to standard. Investigating whether there's a way to do this...

Comment: @metadaddy Are you able to investigate the root cause, we are also facing the same issue

Comment: @LohithMV No - I'm no longer at Salesforce. I suggest you contact Salesforce support.

Comment: @OscarTang were you able figure out the fix for this? even we have the same issue.